# extracting date in java constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I need to validate a date mm/dd from a constructor that receives a string variable. I have tried several ways with no luck. Last I tried was to convert string to ascii and validate that way but is not working either:

```
public Dated(String dateStr)
{
 this.dateStr = dateStr;
 for (int i = 0; i < dateStr.length(); i++)
 {
  char c = dateStr.charAt(i);
  asciiValues = (int) c;      // change each string character to ASCII value

 }

}

public void display()
{
    System.out.println(asciiValues);
}
```

Comment: `mm/dd` or which year? How do you handle leap years?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know you are troubling in parsing the string values. Right.

In java we have a verity of tools available to validate the things like these.

I will be using `SimpleDateFormat` Utility class that can validate the date and also convert the `Date` to `String`

```
public class Dated{

  private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd") // M --> Month; d--> Day

  public Dated(String dateStr) throws Exception{
    try{
      Date d = sdf.parse(dateStr);
      System.out.println( d );
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      // you can throw that exception just to 
      // avoid creating the object of this class
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

But remember that you are not validating the date for Leap Year as mention by `@JB Nizet`.
You can overcome that by validating the Year as well.

In above code if you pass "02/29" you will get the date 1st March. Which is not correct date as 1970 is not a leap year.

So I would include the Year in my date validation as well.

To add the year you can change the SimpleDateFormat as bellow.

```
private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // y --> Year
```

Comment: You'd better throw ParseException from the constructor, and don't use try/catch at all.

Comment: Yes it all depends on the way you want your class Constructor to behave. I added that try/catch so that he can have a good idea.